# Large file uploading

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I want to upload a large file in asp.net app of visual studio 2010. But I have got connection reset error. How can I solve it? Thanks.

P.S I have changed the requestlimited in the webconfig which is not to be make any effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security setting to limit the size of the request. It's a setting called RequestMaxLength in web config. I believe the default is 3 or 4 MB... An asp.net file upload will be limited by the number defined in this setting (any request for that matter).

```
<configuration>  
    <system.web>  
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" executionTimeout="1200" /> 

    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

It's not wise to make this a very large number because it exposes you to DOS attack since someone could just flood your server with huge files. There is also an executionTimeout property that might have to be set as well

Comment: According to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx The default execution timeout is 110 sec. Is your file huge?

Comment: I recommend a chunked uploader if you are uploading huge files. Unfortunately most third party chunked uploaders rely on flash..